# Bind database result array in to form field in php

Tags: php, forms, laravel, codeigniter, model-binding

Normally, when we create an edit form, you would pull in the data of the item you want to edit. Then we would use that to populate your form’s input fields.

Form Model Binding concept in laravel is cool, here is [documentation link](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding), in this we just need to pass result object in model and laravel take care to fill the fields.

Is there any standalone repository/ Project available for this kind of functionality to work with codeigniter or core php?

Comment: haven't tried myself, but here is the [first result of google](https://github.com/fadakar/codeigniter_viewModel_binder).

Comment: Is that repository works?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @apokryfos, i also think same way as you, i posted this question here to know is there any library available or not if yes i want to check out the functionality that i can adopt for my library.

Check below my answer for my library.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [formLib](https://github.com/naranarethiya/formlib) repository on github.

I had used it for more than 20 small and mid level projects.